# Não estou conseguindo mudar a exibição do campo impacto de numérico para um caractere especial

Tags: python, pycharm

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time


headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0'})

data = requests.get('http://br.investing.com/economic-calendar/', headers=headers)

resultados = []

if data.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    info = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')
    
    blocos = ((info.find('table', {'id': 'economicCalendarData'})).find('tbody')).findAll('tr', {'class': 'js-event-item'})
    time.sleep(3)
    
    for blocos2 in blocos:
        impacto = str((blocos2.find('td', {'class': 'sentiment'})).get('data-img_key')).replace('bull','')
        horario = str(blocos2.get('data-event-datetime')).replace('/', '-')
        moeda = (blocos2.find('td', {'class': 'left flagCur noWrap'})).text.strip()
        
        resultados.append({'par': moeda, 'horario': horario, 'impacto': impacto})
        
        
        

for info in resultados: 
        print('PARIDADE:',info['par'],'\nHORARIO:',info['horario'],'\nIMPACTO:',info['impacto'],'\n--------\n')
```

APARECE ASSIM:

```
PARIDADE: GBP 
HORARIO: 2021-03-24 04:00:00 
IMPACTO: 1 
--------

PARIDADE: GBP 
HORARIO: 2021-03-24 04:00:00 
IMPACTO: 1 
--------

PARIDADE: GBP 
HORARIO: 2021-03-24 04:00:00 
IMPACTO: 1 
--------
```

Gostaria que ao invés de mostrar número mostrasse ('⭐')

Comment: Desculpe-me, e tão simples que não consigo nem escrever uma resposta. Fique com o código funcionando https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/scraping

Comment: Nossa só por que você é especialista não pode ajudar uma pessoa com pouco conhecimento ? misericordia

Comment: Opa Boa noite meu amigo pesso minhas mais sinceras desculpas pelo fato de eu ter sido arrogante infelizmente sou novato nesse site muito obrigado de mediato não consegui identificar sua ajuda desculpa mesmo é por que estou com um bot top de linha estou concertando o codigo e não consigo estou com 4 erro esse você quebrou meu galho

Comment: desculpa mesmo obrigado mais uma vez se fosse possivel gostaria de conversar com voce em particular pra ver se mim ajudava nesse bot  ele e top meu alvoroço é por que ja estou quase 3 semanas pénando nesse codigo :'(

Comment: Olá progamaxskynet. O problema não tem haver com esse código todo, só tem haver com converter numero em ⭐, o que poderia ter sido totalmente resumido na pergunta,  é importante você **[edit]** e adicionar **um [mcve] do problema**, com um passo a passo do que já fez e explicar de forma simplificada, clara e objetiva. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). Obrigado por compreender.

Comment: @Augusto Vasques_  NEM DA PRA TE ENVIAR MENSSAGENS